# How to group URLs together?

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I've got dataset like this:

| url | event | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://name/view/adsd-12455-adf1/show | view | 1 |
| https://name/close/anotherpage/12dgksdfgas-adsjasf-54a4551/ | close | 2 |
| https://name/close/anotherpage/98713sdfspdf-asdaj-1/ | close | 3 |
| https://name/view/45asdaj-asdasd-lf5633/show | view | 6 |
| https://name/close/anotherpage/89kkpi-fslo-s521344/ | close | 10 |
| https://name/view/124sfsdf-ajsdasd-551/delete | view | 20 |
| https://name/purchase/6654asdasd-asdfd-asda12 | purchase | 30 |

And let's say all my URLs are in a format like https://name/pagename/anotherpage/123456/randompage where 123456 is like a unique user id in the URL name and is unique to each user. (Note: I've used here 123456 or only numbers for the unique user id as an example only, in practice the user id might also contain letters)

I want to add another column to the dataset that groups together the URLs that refer to the same page, but for a different user. So the table would look like this:

| url | event | timestamp | inferred url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://name/view/adsd-12455-adf1/show | view | 1 | https://name/view/*/show |
| https://name/close/anotherpage/12dgksdfgas-adsjasf-54a4551/ | close | 2 | https://name/close/anotherpage/*/ |
| https://name/close/anotherpage/98713sdfspdf-asdaj-1/ | close | 3 | https://name/close/anotherpage/*/ |
| https://name/view/45asdaj-asdasd-lf5633/show | view | 6 | https://name/view/*/show |
| https://name/close/anotherpage/89kkpi-fslo-s521344/ | close | 10 | https://name/close/anotherpage/*/ |
| https://name/view/124sfsdf-ajsdasd-551/delete | view | 20 | https://name/view/*/delete |
| https://name/purchase/6654asdasd-asdfd-asda12 | purchase | 30 | https://anothername/purchase/*/ |

How could I do this in PySpark? I need help with how to approach this problem.

Edit: Since Steven was right and my example data was too simple, I've changed it a bit

Comment: did you try to do it with regex?

Comment: do you have numbers in the page names ? can it be for example `https://name/purchase_2/665412` ? If you cannot create a simple rule to identify the user id, you're doomed. And I think you oversimplified your problem, you should add some real data otherwise we might give an incomplete solution.

Comment: @eshirvana I'm working with too many pages in order to use regex for each of them, sadly

Comment: @Steven From what I know there are no numbers in other page names in the URLs when the URL contains an userid, but there can be URLs like https://name/pagename/2020/view with numbers that are used to refer to a year. I'm not allowed to publicly post the data I'm working with

Comment: @user16679629 Sorry but in this condition, I do not think anybody could help you. If you manage to define a clear rule to separate a page id and a user id, maybe we can do something but currently, it is not possible.

Comment: @Steven Solving the problem for the examples that I posted would be helpful enough. You can assume there are no numbers in the pages. They appear very rarely and there's a margin of error I can work within

Comment: @user16679629 you can try spark regexp_replace function

Comment: @user16679629 i've seen your update. are the IDs always with dash `-` ? if so, we can match something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a solution with your sample case, then it is just a regex :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 

df.withColumn("inferred_url", F.regexp_replace("url", r"\d+", "\*")).show(
    truncate=False
)
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------+
|url                                   |event   |timestamp|inferred_url                     |
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------+
|https://name/view/124551/show         |view    |1        |https://name/view/*/show         |
|https://name/close/anotherpage/124551/|close   |2        |https://name/close/anotherpage/*/|
|https://name/close/anotherpage/987131/|close   |3        |https://name/close/anotherpage/*/|
|https://name/view/455633/show         |view    |6        |https://name/view/*/show         |
|https://name/close/anotherpage/891344/|close   |10       |https://name/close/anotherpage/*/|
|https://name/view/124551/delete       |view    |20       |https://name/view/*/delete       |
|https://anothername/purchase/665412   |purchase|30       |https://anothername/purchase/*   |
+--------------------------------------+--------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

---

if you want to add a bit more of complexity, let say, assuming user id contains at least one number and maybe other char, then you can do this :

```py
df.withColumn(
    "inferred_url", F.regexp_replace("url", r"\/[^\/]*\d[^\/]*", "\/\*")
).show(truncate=False)
```

---

version with excluding "a2z":

```py
import re 

@F.udf
def infer_url(url):
    user_id_re = re.compile(r"\/([^\/]*\d[^\/]*)")
    user_id_list = user_id_re.findall(url)
    for user_id in user_id_list:
        if "a2z" not in user_id:
            url = url.replace(user_id, "*")
    return url

df.withColumn("user_id", infer_url(F.col("url"))).show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------------------------------+
|url                                    |event   |timestamp|user_id                           |
+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------------------------------+
|https://name/view/124551/show          |view    |1        |https://name/view/*/show          |
|https://name/close/anotherpage/124551/ |close   |2        |https://name/close/anotherpage/*/ |
|https://name/close/anotherpage/987131/ |close   |3        |https://name/close/anotherpage/*/ |
|https://name/view/455633/show          |view    |6        |https://name/view/*/show          |
|https://name/close/anotherpage/891344/ |close   |10       |https://name/close/anotherpage/*/ |
|https://name/view/124551/delete        |view    |20       |https://name/view/*/delete        |
|https://anothername/purchase/665412    |purchase|30       |https://anothername/purchase/*    |
|https://anothername/purchase_a2z/665412|purchase|31       |https://anothername/purchase_a2z/*|
+---------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, you were right. The example I posted is too simple.  But thank you for your help. If instead of only numbers I would also have letters in the user id, what could I do?

Comment: @user16679629 `F.regexp_replace("url", "\/[^\/]*\d[^\/]*", "\/\*")`

Comment: That's great! This almost solves my problem actually! Thanks! Is it possible to also add an exception to regex so that if it sees somewhere "a2z" it doesn't replace the text with *? I'm not very familiar with regex, but if that was possible it would 99% solve the problem (or to what I think is a reasonable percentage of error)

Comment: @user16679629 Each case you add changes drasticaly the code ... there is no universal solution, specifically with regex